# Would like to vectorize while loop for performance

Tags: python, numpy

1. I am trying to set values for a window of an array based on the current value of another array.
2. It should ignore values that the windown overrides.
3. I need to be able to change the size of the window for different runs.

This works but it is very slow.
I thought there would be a vectorized solution somewhere.

```
window_size=3

def signal(self):
    signal = pd.Series(data=0, index=arr.index)
    i = 0
    while i < len(self.arr) - 1: 
        s = self.arr.iloc[i]
        if s in [-1, 1]:
            j = i + window_size
            signal.iloc[i: j] = s
            i = i + window_size
        else:
            i += 1
    return signal

arr    = [0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 -1 -1  0 0 0 0 ]

signal = [0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 -1 -1 -1 0 0 0 ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `shift` function of `pd.Series`

```
arr_series = pd.Series(arr)

arr_series + arr_series.shift(periods=1, fill_value=0) + arr_series.shift(periods=2, fill_value=0)
```

Comment: Hi SIA.  I have updated the question with more specific requirements.

Comment: @ItayFeldman, note that once you have an answer that's correct for the question you asked, it's more appropriate to accept that answer and ask a new/different question that more accurately reflects your requirements, should it turn out that what you asked and what you need don't quite match up.